# Error with Kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, pagination, kaminari

I would like to paginate my objects with the Kaminari pagination gem. I have this line in my controller:

```
@products = Product.order("id").find_all_by_id(params[:id])
```

That line in my view:

```
<%= paginate @products %>
```

And that line in my model:

```
paginates_per 20
```

When I open my page where my objects are supposed to be listed, I have this error message :

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x2964690>
```

The exception is raised at my `<%= paginate @products %>` line.

I have already made a pagination for another project and it was working really great. Could someone help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:

The problem is that `find_all_by_*` returns an array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation.

You can do something like this instead

```
@products = Product.order("id").where("id IN (?)", params[:id])
```

Also, you should probably have a `.page(params[:page])` in there.

Comment: I get the same error. I tried
 `@products = Product.order("id").find_all_by_id(params[:id]).page(params[:page])
` and
`@products = Product.order("id").page(params[:page]).find_all_by_id(params[:id])
`
but it still don't work.

Comment: Yes, but there is only one value in the array. It is not really clear, but my products are classified by categories and the `:id` is actually the category's id that the products in my list belongs to. If I do not put the pagination, I have the full list of my products in the category I've chosen before (`:id`). The problem is only when I set the pagination.

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert you have cleared My concept, i am searching for this since long. A where condition for this works with pagination.